# How to dual boot macOS and encrypted Debian with rEFInd?

Tags: debian, dual-boot, lvm, grub, luks

I am trying to run Debian on a MacBook Pro which runs macOS Catalina. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Install rEFInd on macOS.
2. Install Debian from a bootable flash drive. The Debian is fully encrypted according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577765): I created an encrypted volume, and then added four logical volumes for boot, root, home, and swap.

After the installation is finished, I get a few error message which look like this:

error: failure reading sector … from hd0/1/2

I am pretty new to rEFInd, and I am not sure if adding any flags will resolve the issue, similar to [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263686).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My response to another thread on stackexchange

Now I have a 2016 MacBook pro with full disk encryption, csr enabled, triple boot efi boot lnx 5.11, win 10, osx Monterrey, all working perfectly and with independent diskencryption.

Thank you

Happy Mac

Procedure:

Recovery boot
Terminal: csrutil disable!!!!!!
USB Stick with rEFInd, install
Boot in to osx, split disk or don't, always format FAT32, change later to ext3,4, disk-install bootloader to same partition on

Mac...usb disk then install bootloader to USB disk.

Reboot, install debian with disk encryption luks/lvm which disk type ( internal or USB) is not important, wright partition is!!!

Reboot check if debian is encrypted and accessible
Reboot recovery, install rEFInd again
Reboot recovery, csrutil enable
Reboot osx turn on filevault
Reboot check everything

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please consider adding a link to the other answer of yours that you refer to.

Comment: @gvel50 Does this work even if Debian's `boot` partition is encrypted?